# This won't work? Any suggestions?

Tags: php, mysql

I've got this script I'm working on to rate music, there are no errors, and I'm getting 'Data Inserted', I'm aware I haven't escaped the data yet, but are there any problems in this script that might be preventing it from putting the inserted data in to the database?

```
 <?
    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/assets/global/scripts/connect.php');
    $songname = $_GET['songname'];
    $artist = $_GET['artist'];
    $ratenum = 1; 
    $chkquery = "SELECT * FROM hotmuze_music WHERE songname='$songname'";
    $plusOneQuery = "SELECT * FROM hotmuze_music WHERE songname='$songname'";
    $updateQuery = "UPDATE hotmuze_music SET rating='$rating2' WHERE songname='$songname'";
    $checkdata = mysql_query($chkquery);
    $checkrows = mysql_num_rows($checkdata); 
    if($checkrows==0) 
    {
    $insquery = "INSERT INTO hotmuze_music (id, songname, artist, sex, genre, rating, promoted) VALUES('', '$songname', '$artist', '', '$genre' '$ratenum')";
    $insdata = mysql_query($insquery); 
    } 


    if($checkrows!=0) 
    { 
    $plusData = mysql_query($plusOneQuery);
    }

    if(mysql_num_rows($plusData)!=0) 
    {
    $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($plusData);
    $rating = $result['ratng'];
    $rating2 = $rating+1;
    mysql_query($updateQuery); 
    echo "Data Inserted";
    } 
    ?>
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: Check for errors: `mysql_foo() or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: `$rating = $result['ratng'];` should probably be `$rating = $result['rating'];`

Comment: you didnt sent 'promoted' column value when you insert. Also there is no coma after '$Genre'

Comment: It doesn't make sense to echo data inserted when you haven't actually tested that the data was indeed inserted.

Comment: Just a suggestion, but you might want to look into the MySQL INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE syntax. It would make this a lot easier for you.

Comment: thanks for all your help! but i'm still getting the error 'Column count doesn't match value count at row 1', any ideas? :) the echoing is just in case if there is an error, haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're getting `Column count doesn't match value count at row 1` is caused by missing 1 more DB column in your insert statement.

`(id, songname, artist, sex, genre, rating, promoted)` are 7 fields and you're only giving values for 6 which is `VALUES('', '$songname', '$artist', '', '$genre' '$ratenum')";`

Answer (score 1):

You missed a comma, and value for promoted field as well, try:

```
$insquery = "INSERT INTO hotmuze_music (id, songname, artist, sex, genre, rating, promoted) VALUES('', '$songname', '$artist', '', '$genre', '$ratenum', '$promoted')";
```

Comment: thanks for that :) although the error returned is 'Column count doesn't match value count at row 1', any ideas? :)

Answer (score 1):

You define the `$updateQuery` at the top of the script referencing a variable (`$rating2`) which isn't yet defined.  Try changing the last lines to:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($plusData)!=0) 
{
  $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($plusData);
  $rating = $result['rating'];
  $rating2 = $rating+1;
  mysql_query("UPDATE hotmuze_music SET rating='$rating2' WHERE songname='$songname'"); 
  echo "Data Inserted";
}
```

Comment: Also see @Sudhir's comment regarding a missing comma in the insert.

Comment: thanks for that :) although the error returned is 'Column count doesn't match value count at row 1', any ideas? :)